# Database trying to join/Difference on mysql tables/results

Tags: mysql, database, join

1.Trying to query the numbers sold of each item and their names, within the database which is working fine.

2.However i am also trying to Query the item names that have not sold within that month

so far i have tried this and for (1) its working..

```
(SELECT SUM(bagel_quantity) AS Total_Sold, soldBagel.Bagel_Name as Sold FROM
    Shop_Order_CONTAINS_Bagel,
    Bagel soldBagel,
    Shop_Order

WHERE
    Shop_Order_Contains_Bagel.BagelID = soldBagel.BagelID
        AND Shop_Order.Order_Date LIKE '____-02-__'
        AND Shop_Order.OrderNumber = Shop_Order_CONTAINS_Bagel.OrderNumber
GROUP BY soldBagel.Bagel_Name)
```

RESULT:

```
+------------+-------------------+
| Total_Sold | Sold              |
+------------+-------------------+
|          7 | Onion Bagel       |
|          4 | Strawberry Bagel  |
|          2 | Water Poppy Bagel |
+------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

However for (2) i am trying to display another column after sold with the names of the items which have't sold and i've tried the following which is a partial idea as it does't have the full functionality nor does it work correctly

```
(SELECT SUM(bagel_quantity) AS Total_Sold, soldBagel.Bagel_Name as Sold, notSoldBagel.Bagel_Name as Not_Sold FROM
    Shop_Order_CONTAINS_Bagel,
    Bagel soldBagel,
    Bagel notSoldBagel,
    Shop_Order

WHERE
    Shop_Order_Contains_Bagel.BagelID = soldBagel.BagelID
        AND Shop_Order.Order_Date LIKE '____-02-__'
        AND Shop_Order.OrderNumber = Shop_Order_CONTAINS_Bagel.OrderNumber
GROUP BY soldBagel.Bagel_Name, notSoldBagel.Bagel_Name)
```

RESULT:

```
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Total_Sold | Sold              | Not_Sold          |
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|          7 | Onion Bagel       | Bananna Nut Bagel |
|          7 | Onion Bagel       | Egg Bagel         |
|          7 | Onion Bagel       | Onion Bagel       |
|          7 | Onion Bagel       | Strawberry Bagel  |
|          7 | Onion Bagel       | Water Poppy Bagel |
|          4 | Strawberry Bagel  | Bananna Nut Bagel |
|          4 | Strawberry Bagel  | Egg Bagel         |
|          4 | Strawberry Bagel  | Onion Bagel       |
|          4 | Strawberry Bagel  | Strawberry Bagel  |
|          4 | Strawberry Bagel  | Water Poppy Bagel |
|          2 | Water Poppy Bagel | Bananna Nut Bagel |
|          2 | Water Poppy Bagel | Egg Bagel         |
|          2 | Water Poppy Bagel | Onion Bagel       |
|          2 | Water Poppy Bagel | Strawberry Bagel  |
|          2 | Water Poppy Bagel | Water Poppy Bagel |
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
15 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

it seems to be doing the cartesian product on correct output of the old statement for (1) which has attribute names as 'Total_Sold' and 'Sold'

Comment: You need to get familiar with outer joins.

Comment: Do not use comma join syntax. Ever.

Comment: If you want to remove the question, then delete, do not just change the text!

Comment: **Moderator note**: please don't vandalise your own post

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an outer join to get all records from a table (`bagel`):

```
SELECT SUM(bagel_quantity) AS Total_Sold, soldBagel.Bagel_Name FROM
    Bagel soldBagel
    left join Shop_Order_CONTAINS_Bagel on Shop_Order_Contains_Bagel.BagelID = soldBagel.BagelID
    left join Shop_Order on Shop_Order.OrderNumber = Shop_Order_CONTAINS_Bagel.OrderNumber and Shop_Order.Order_Date LIKE '____-02-__' 
GROUP BY soldBagel.Bagel_Name
```

This way the bagels not sold in the period will have 0 in the sold column.

If you want sold and not sold in separate columns, then use if() function or case statement based on the outcome of sum(): `if(sum(bagel_quantity)=0, bagel_name, null) as unsold`

Comment: When i implemented this its returning the exact result as my (1) solution however how can i implement this for the functionality as my desired (2) problem?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to move the remaining condition from where into the join criteria. See updated code.

Comment: yeah i would like separate columns however i'm not too good with using an if statement in mysql, how would this be achieved?

Comment: I gave you the code for unsold, based on this do it for the sold.

Comment: its not functioning correctly its returning all bagels

Comment: Pls provide appropriate feedback including what you have tried.